# Bookmarks API - getBookmarks(context.getUser().getMail()

Tags: xpages, ibm-sbt

I am working with the IBM SBT SDK. For the Get My Bookmarks and Get Popular Bookmarks routines the user will be identified via:

```
var bkmkSvc = new com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.bookmarks.BookmarkService("connections"); 
var bkmks = bkmkSvc.getBookmarks(context.getUser().getMail());
```

In my case the app resides on on premise Domino and connections I use greenhouse for now.

context.getUser().getMail() returns nothing since I am not authenticated for Domino.

How can I use the userid from connections instead to collect my bookmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a call to ProfileService 
https://greenhouse.lotus.com/sbt/SBTPlayground.nsf/JavaSnippets.xsp#snippet=Social_Profiles_Get_My_Profile

```
ProfileService connProfSvc = new ProfileService();
Profile profile = connProfSvc.getMyProfile();
out.println("my UserId "+profile.getUserid()+"<br>");
```

then you can use the id to make the request to the backend bookmarks.
getBookmarks(String id) <- uses the id anyway...

I hope this helps